# Unknown "JE07" SMD SOT-89-3 Regulator

Tags: identification, surface-mount, linear-regulator

Can someone please help in identifying what this "JE07" SMD is? All I know is that 28V goes to the tab of the sot-89-3 smd part which is also the middle pin. I assume that is the input pin. Pin 3 is connected to ground. Pin 1 is connected to a big filter capacitor. I can assume that to be the output pin.

[image]